# Less can define the function like sass “@function” ？

Tags: css, less

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhTxg.png)

Can less define functions like sass, eg. `@function`?

Comment: you can use a mixin like a function, read the documentation: http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature

Answer (score -1):

```
.px-to-percent(@px, @base){
  @percent: unit(((@px / @base) * 100), %);
}

.myclass{
  .px-to-percent(456, 1200);
  width: @percent;
}
```